# How to flatten a tree-like data store to a key-value data store in Java?

Tags: java, database, database-design

I am having a tree-like data store. There are Read and Write transaction taking place on the data. The data is to be replicated across a cluster for the sake of scalability. Each time a transaction is happening, I have to flatten the tree to a key-value store, replicate the data to cluster, and then de-flatten back to tree. I appreciate any best practices or suggested way of doing this.

Comment: Probably an xml based database can be used

Comment: Also a complete flatten and restore sounds expensive.   Perhaps you can simply send the deltas around the cluster.